# how can i fix this error when i try to Using External Database and API's with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, database, swift, macos

i try to using external database and api's. so i follow from this video in youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ixk93yx-v28

and i see this error

"Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; " on that line

```
    func request(url:String,callback:(NSDictionary)->()) {
    var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
    ///////////////////////////on this line/////////////////////////////////
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL) {
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        (data,response,error) in
        var error:NSError?
        var response = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as NSDictionary
        callback(response)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

and when i try to fix by put `!` in nsURL like this
xCode return this error "Extra argument 'error' in call "

```
func request(url:String,callback:(NSDictionary)->()) {
    var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!) {
        (data,response,error) in
        var error:NSError?
////////////////////////////Error Here/////////////////////////////////////
            var response = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as NSDictionary
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        callback(response)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

have any ideal ? sorry for my english

Comment: Double-click on the name of the function giving an error, then right-click and choose "Jump to definition". This will take you to the definition of the function in its header file, so you can see what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your function as shown below for swift 2.0:

```
func request(url:String,callback:(NSDictionary)->()) {
    guard let nsURL = NSURL(string: url) else { return }
    ///////////////////////////on this line/////////////////////////////////
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL) {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
        do {
            if let response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                callback(response) 
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }


    }
    task.resume()
}
```